# Can we say $L^p \implies {L^ \infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to verify when $u(x) \in L^p$, $x \in [0, \infty)$

then can we say  $u(x) \in L^{ \infty}$, $x \in [0, \infty)$ ?

Where $u$ is any function with variable x, and $L^p$ is talking about Lebesgue spaces.

If not, please give me an counterexample

or we could derive that result by adding any conditions?

Comment: What is $u$? What is $x$? What is $L$? What is $p$?

Comment: Are we talking about norms here?

Comment: @BenCollister yes, we are.

Comment: @Klangen $u$ is any function with variable $x$, $L^p$ is Lebesgue spaces.

Comment: @Zi-YingZhan Then please include that in your question. We are not telepathic.

Comment: @Klangen Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

No. For any $1 \le p < +\infty$ set $u(x) = \frac1{x^{1/2p}}\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$. Then

$$\int_0^\infty|u(x)|^p\,dx = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} < +\infty$$

so $u \in L^p(0, \infty)$. However, for any $M \ge 1$ we have $u \ge M$ on $\left(0, \frac1{M^{2p}}\right)$ which is a set of positive measure so $u \notin L^\infty(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

In general the implication $u\in L^p(\Omega) \implies u \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ is false.

For example, if the space $\Omega$ has finite measure (e.g. $\Omega=[0,1]$) it is the converse to hold:

$$u\in L^\infty(\Omega) \implies u \in L^p(\Omega) \quad \forall p\in [1,\infty],$$

and more in general:

$$u\in L^q(\Omega) \implies u \in L^p(\Omega) \quad \forall 1\le p \le q \le \infty.$$

One counterexample is simply $f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt x},$ for $x\in (0,1):$ it belongs to $L^1((0,1))$ but not to $L^\infty((0,1)).$

If you look for something similar to the converse to this last statement for general $\Omega$ there is this implication: 
$$f\in L^\infty(\Omega) \implies \left(f\in L^p \implies f\in L^q\right) \quad \forall 1\le p\le q\le \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact for a given  measure space the inclusion $L^p\subset L^\infty$ holds if and only if $$\inf\{\mu(E):\mu(E)>0\}>0.$$(Which holds for counting measure, for example.)